# Twitter bootstrap not getting the page layout I want

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap for my layout and at the moment This is what my page looks like :

[image]

I would like to move the ‘Fitness is our goal’ Text flush underneath the big picture - but due to the way my layout is handled it is not happening.

At the moment I have the following layout:

```
div class="col-md-12">
<h3>
  class name here
</h3>
</div>

<div class="col-md-8">
big picture here
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4”>

all details on right hand column here - ending with address
 </div>

<div class="col-md-8”>
Fitness is our goal text - it is this div I want moved up flush underneath the image
</div>
```

The result I want is:

[image]

Please help!

Comment: So why don't you put the text right below the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it break your layout to move the text into the image's column, like so:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<h3>
  class name here
</h3>
</div>

<div class="col-md-8">
big picture here

Fitness is our goal text - it is this div I want moved up flush underneath the image
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4”>

all details on right hand column here - ending with address
 </div>
```

If not that then you might also want to make sure you don't have a wrapper around that image which is forcing a certain size ratio, adding space between it and the next column.

Answer (score 1):

When you chose to put the image and the text in the same column, you don't have to say it twice. Keep them in the same column, in separate row.

Try this...

```
...
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
        big picture here
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        Fitness is our goal text - it is this div I want moved up flush underneath the image
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4”>
    all details on right hand column here - ending with address
</div>
...
```

Comment: What difference does the 2 rows make? If i dont add them i seem to get the same result, so what is the benefit in using rows?

Comment: Nothing but the semantic meaning. If you have columns, you should have rows. Otherwise, same thing. Also, there are some styles applied to the "row" class.